# Where's the Segmentation fault in this program?

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

On compiling the following program, I am running into a Segmentation fault(core dumped).

I am using MinGW compiler for compilation.

The program is supposed to accept a valid POSTFIX expression in form of a string, then traverse the entire string from left to right and evaluate it. It should send the result back to the main() which is then displayed on the console.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef enum {plus,minus,mul,divide,mod,eos,opnd} precedence;


int evaluate(char postfix[]);
precedence get_token();

void push(int number,int *top, int stk[]);
int pop(int *top,int stk[]);
int operation(int op1, int op2, precedence token);


int main(){
    char postfix[10];
    printf("Enter a valid POSTFIX EXPRESSION\n");
    scanf("%s",postfix);
    puts(postfix);
    printf("\n The result of the expression is %d ",evaluate(postfix));
    return 0;
    }

precedence get_token(char *symbol, int *n, char postfix[]){
    *symbol = postfix[*n++];
        switch(*symbol){

        case '+': return plus;
                  break;
        case '-': return minus;
                  break;
        case '*': return mul;
                  break;
        case '/': return divide;
                  break;
        case '%': return mod;
                  break;
        case '\0':return eos;
                  break;
        default :return opnd;
                    break;
        }//end of switch
}//end of get_token()


int evaluate(char postfix[]){

    int stk[10], res,top=-1,n=0,op1,op2,result;
    char symbol;

    precedence token= get_token(&symbol,&n, postfix);

        while(token!=eos){
            if(token==opnd){
                push(symbol-'0',&top,stk);
            }

            else{

                op2= pop(&top,stk);
                op1=pop(&top,stk);

                result=operation(op1,op2,token);

                push(result,&top,stk);
                    }//end of else

                    token=get_token(&symbol,&n,postfix);
        }//end of while

        res=pop(&top,stk);
        return res;
        }//end of evaluate()

void push(int number, int *top, int stk[]){

    stk[++(*top)]=number;
}


int pop(int *top, int stk[]){
        return stk[(*top)--];
        }

int operation(int op1, int op2, precedence token){

switch(token){
    case plus: return op1+op2;
    case minus: return op1-op2;
    case mul: return op1*op2;
    case divide: return op1/op2;
    case mod: return op1%op2;
}//end of switch
}// end of operation()
```

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Comment: Are you saying the compiler breaks?

Comment: May not a cause for seg fault but - `#include "stdio.h"` ???? This is to be `#include <stdio.h>` same with other one .

Comment: @Magisch i tried adding a watch to stk[ ] and postfix[ ] but that didn't help

Comment: @ameyCU "stdio.h" and <stdio.h> are the same that's not the error. It's a runtime error

Comment: `*symbol = postfix[*n++];` --> `*symbol = postfix[(*n)++];`

Comment: why do you need pointer to integers , i.e. `int *n` ?

Comment: @WeatherVane well the code compiles successfully, it doesn't execute, on Ubuntu it throws a segmentation fault while on Windows the command prompt crashes.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis I'm using n  as a counter to iterate through the POSTFIX expression that the user entered. I'm extracting each individual character and comparing if its and operand or operator and then I'm pushing and popping respectively.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks that solved it :D